# Why am i getting Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, compile-error

```
Public class productavailcheck{

    public string PID{get; set;}
    public list<inventory__c> productlist{get; set;}

    public productavailcheck(){

        productlist   =[select Stocks__c,productid__c,name from Inventory__c where productid__c =: PID];

    } 

    public pagereference finalbuybutton(){


        for(inventory__c stcheck : productlist)
            if(PID==stcheck.productid__c) 
            {

                productlist.stocks__c = productlist.stocks__c - 1;

            }
        update productlist;




        return null;
    }





}
```

PID is passed from another VF page through pagereference.
in the if condition when i try to use products__c or stocks__c ,it shows me the error

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: stocks__c at line 19 column 18

and when that if block is empty, no compile errors are there.
What is that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `List` does not have any property named `Stocks__c`. You need to reference the individual record, not the collection.

**Collection**

```
for (Inventory__c record : productList)
{
    productList.Stocks__c ...
}
```

**Record**

```
for (Inventory__c record : productList)
{
    record.Stocks__c ...
}
```

In your case, you need to change `productList.Stocks__c` to `stcheck.Stocks__c`.

Answer (score 2):

Productlist is a list of Inventory__c objects. And your are trying to access stocks__c from the List, whereas you should access it from individual record.
Use [] operator to access the record from the list.